# Conditional replacement of specific row values

Tags: r, replace, row, conditional-statements

I have a problem with conditional replacement. Let's assume I have the following code for a dataframe

```
a=c("0","1","0","B","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA")
b=c(0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1)
c=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1)
d=c("0","1","0","0","1","0","B","NA","NA")
dat=data.frame(rbind(a,b,c,d))
names(dat)=c("P1","P2","P3","P4","C1","C2","C3","C4","C5")
```

Now I want to replace the row values of P1:P4 with NA if one of these values is B and I also want to replace the row values of C1:C5 with NA if one of these values is B. So I want the Dataframe to look like this:

```
a=c(**"NA","NA","NA","NA"**,"NA","NA","NA","NA","NA")
b=c(0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1)
c=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1)
d=c("0","1","0","0",**"NA","NA","NA"**,"NA","NA")
dat=data.frame(rbind(a,b,c,d))
names(dat)=c("P1","P2","P3","P4","C1","C2","C3","C4","C5")
```

I hope the problem is understandable and I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering dat to be the original provided dataframe, I'm providing a comparatively lengthy code for better understanding. Hope it helps.

```
dat2 <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){

  datSubset <- with(dat, dat[i,])
  col.num.of.B <- which(datSubset == "B", arr.ind = T)[2]
  if(is.na(col.num.of.B)){
    datSubset <- datSubset
  } else if(col.num.of.B < 5) {
    datSubset[,c(1:4)] <- NA
  } else {
    datSubset[,c(5:9)] <- NA
  }

  dat2 <- rbind(dat2, datSubset) 
}
```

---

```
dat2
#    P1   P2   P3   P4   C1   C2   C3   C4   C5

# a <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# b    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    1
# c    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    1
# d    0    1    0    0 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you both. This was exactly what I needed :)

Comment: @Lilly - If the answer does justice to your question, kindly mark it as the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood it... If the value `B` is found in columns P1 to P4, then set all the values within P1 to P4 to `NA`.

You can try:

```
nm <- c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4")
cols <- which(names(dat) %in% nm) 
dat[,cols][any(dat[,cols] == "B")] <- NA

dat
#   P1 P2 P3 P4 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
# a NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# b NA NA NA NA  1  0  1  0  1
# c NA NA NA NA  1  0  0  1  1 
# d NA NA NA NA  1  0  B NA NA
```

If you want to apply this to only the first row, then use `dat[1,cols][any(dat[,cols] == "B")] <- NA`.